# How to find out the ip of target machine and register in some variable for later use using ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to find out the ip of target machine and register it in some variable
I got the ip of target machine using below, but not getting how can I register that ip for later use.

IP of target machine

```yaml
debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
```

Comment: Note that you can shortcut to `ansible_default_ipv4.address` (or `ansible_default_ipv4['address']`). You can use this as is, or create a var somewhere expanding this expression, either in your inventory, your playbook, your role, or with the `set_fact` module.

Comment: The [general doc on ansible variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables-with-jinja2) might be a worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

Registering a variable is basically done using [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html):

```yaml
- set_fact:
    target_ip: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"
- name: Write this the target IP to a file
  copy:
    content: "{{ target_ip }}"
    dest: /etc/mine.conf
```

But since, it is in the `hostvars` already, you could as well use it, right away, from there:

```yaml
- name: Write this the target IP to a file
  copy:
    content: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"
    dest: /etc/mine.conf
```